# General Relativity Lorentz-like equation

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics, linearized-theory

In the literature, it says that, in the weak-field, 
$$g_{µν} = η_{µν} +h_{µν},$$
slow-motion limit, the Geodesic equation reduces to the Lorentz-like equation.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Maybe it is related to the fact that is you keep only first order in h (which is almost always what books do) you are neglecting some of the backreaction effects? Right now I don't know if the geodesic equation becomes really algebraically similar to the Lorentz eqs, but I'll check.

Comment: Which literature? What is a "Lorentz-like" equation?